# Does anybody have any ideas about the trend that I found for luminol chemiluminescence reaction? Or can anybody help me analyze them?

Tags: ph

The reaction that I did is shown below. I'm testing the duration and luminosity of the light the reaction produces against different pH. The way I used to control the pH is by adding more or less $\ce{Na2CO3}$ since it is basic with a pH of 11.

Solution A: In $\pu{200 ml}$ water, add in $\pu{0.16 g}$ $\ce{Na2CO3}$, $\pu{0.04 g}$ luminol, $\pu{5 g}$ $\ce{NaHCO3}$, $\pu{4.6 g}$ $\ce{(NH4)2CO3}$, and $\pu{0.08 g}$ $\ce{CuSO4}$.
Solution B: In $\pu{200 ml}$ water, add in $\pu{10 ml}$ $\ce{H2O2}$

Then, pouring $\pu{50 ml}$ of solution B into $\pu{50 ml}$ of solution A, a bright light will be produced. The light will gradually fade away but the light will be produced again after some time, a guaranteed second reaction for every trial. (Could someone also tell me how could this happen?)

The trend that I found is shown below:[image]

[image]

Comment: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jpcb.0c06301